# C# - Selenium cannot locate elements produced by JS

Tags: c#, selenium

I have some code to execute Selenium, but Selenium is unable to update the `PageSource` it uses to locate elements.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\chrome-driver\\75", new ChromeOptions(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));                
driver.Url = "https://website.com";

Thread.Sleep(10000); // Gives it time to process the internal JS

IWebElement emailTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='text1']"));
IWebElement passwordTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='text2']"));
IWebElement signUpButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='button']"));

emailTextBox.SendKeys("email");
passwordTextBox.SendKeys("password");
signUpButton.Click();
```

The problem is that Selenium only uses the page as it was downloaded, but in reality the user will use a web-page partially rendered by JavaScript, so Selenium is seeing, eg.:

```
<html>
  Hello World
  <script src="code.js"/>
</html>
```

While the actual page (after rendering), contains all the components for login.

The URL of the login is: https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.investors.com%2Fstock-lists%2Fbig-cap-20%2F

And you will notice that if you try to locate the `Email` TextBox to input the email, it is actually never found. The `Xpath` for the `Email` is `//*[@id="gigya-login-form"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/input`.

So, how can I make Selenium to get aware of the modifications made by JS?

Comment: Use a WebDriverWait along with an expected condition.  It will re-poll the DOM until element is found.

Comment: @pcalkins Perhaps an example can illustrate better your suggestion. Traditional use of WebDriverWait seems not to work in this case.

Comment: post the markup.  You can see the current page's markup by inspecting the page in the browser.  Right-click on the element and choose "Inspect".

Comment: to be clear... on .get() Selenium will wait for a pageready state.  By that time the script is done populating the DOM. (in most cases...)  So a normal call will work fine.  However, if events going forward do not trigger a pageload, you'll need to use a WebDriverWait.  This will make Selenium poll the DOM for a certain interval until it finds a certain condition to be true.  (During loading of any dynamic elements.)  You can see basic example code here:  https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: @pcalkins The post contains now the URL of the webpage I am trying to automate and insert the Login/Password, as you will notice, Selenium never load the complete web-page.

Comment: Should be able to find it using name="username"... so //input[@name='username']

Comment: @pcalkins This is the results: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":" //input[@name='username']"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)`. I also tried with `Protractor` and received the same results.

Comment: ok, there are two problems there... one is that they are detecting you as a bot.  The other is that the login stuff is inserted as an iframe:  id="signin-iframe".  They need to allow you to login as a bot.  Then you can switch the driver to the iframe before typing.